# Price change in magmi magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magmi

I am looking the way to change price in percentage in magmi. Something like adding 30% on price.

Comment: Details, details, details. Database structure, what are you going to do..

Comment: Do you already have a Magmi datasource file?  You could write a simple plugin that intercepts the price, calculates 30% and adds it to the price column before Magmi processes it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am doing that with excel,but i think value replacer in magmi does the job.but just need to find the code for it.

Comment: You really need to be more descriptive.  You say you're doing it in Excel.  Does that mean you have a column with the values you want assigned to the price?  Again I say, post an example of your CSV you are trying to import into Magmi.